# Scandinavian letter Ø triggers math error

Tags: input-encodings

I'm writting an article in Norwegian, and thereby I'm required to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

This package allows my name to be spelled correctly (Øyvind). But some of my Ø's result in a math error. The result of some Ø's is here (omegas are replacements for Ø apparently)[image]

If I change the package to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, no error and no  warnings are displayed (but also no scandinavian letters). However `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` results in 10+ errors with only 20% of the letters displayed correctly.

My current test document consists of

```
\begin{article}
hello Æ Ø Å\\
hello ÆØÅ
æøå
\end{article}
```

with the results: 
[image]( The two coloumns article style makes the newline appears like a hskip) The first two lines here are displaying the letters correctly, but the last is not..

Any idea why? and how to solve that?

Im using this template: [PNAS Journal](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/pnas), article with two coloumns

tnx Ø

Comment: replacing the missplaced ÆØÅ with \ae \oe \aa doesn't work..

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: What would happen if you put both in your preamble `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example. I just tried your code snippet (where "article" is replaced by "document") and prefixed it with "\documentclass{article}" and "\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}" and got no errors. So your problem must lie in the rest of the preamble and/or if you use pdflatex, lualatex, ... - Also, please post the actual error messages.

Comment: if the letters are working before you added `[utf8]` the file is not stored in UTF-8 (it is probably in latin-1 (iso-8859-1)) so use `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` or save the file  in UTF-8 using your editor.

Comment: I suspected as you stated DCTLib, that the error was within the preamble.. 
After some trail and error I've located it towards the 'title' command. Making a new from the beginning. 

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Please, make the minimal example complete with the preamble, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you're using [`pnas-new.cls`](http://www.pnas.org/sites/default/files/advanced-pages/pnas-new.cls) it already sets the encoding with `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}`. There also seems to be a `pnastwo.cls` file, which doesn't. This is why the comments keep asking you to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) because the solution depends on the class you're using. For example, `\documentclass{pnastwo} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \begin{document} Æ Ø Å \end{document}`

Comment: If you're using `pnastwo`, you're basically doomed, because the class uses quite nonstandard methods for loading fonts. If you prefer to use *blatantly wrong* instead of *quite nonstandard*, you may be nearer to the truth.